# Show a Form in my template base using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

In my base template, I want to include a search form.

I already created it, but I'm wondering if there is a better option than passing the `form` to all my templates that extend the base?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yea, this is what template context processors are useful for. They allow you to pass a variable to all your templates without having to specify.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',

    ...

    'some_app.context_processors.search_form',
)
```

**context_processors.py** (you place this in one of your apps, or in the main directory if you prefer)

```
from my_forms import MySearchForm

def search_form(request):
return {
     'search_form' : MySearchForm()
}
```

Now you can use the **{{ search_form** }} in all of you templates

Comment: Interesting. I've never actually used context processors. I'll have to start doing this.

Comment: Just a question: can I change the signature of the `search_form` function? I mean, could I add more parameters? Sometimes I want to bind the form instead of create it empty.

Comment: Guess, it should be something like: return {'search_form': MySearchForm()}

Comment: When returning the form search_form should be 'search_form'

Answer (score 1):

You could make it into a filter that returns the form, assuming it's static. It would then look something like this:

```
<body>
...
{% import_form_template %}
...
</body>
```

Or something along those lines. You can also make it so it takes arguments if you needed it to be a bit more dynamic:

```
{% import_form_template arg1 arg2 arg3 %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. I'll work on it now and I'll let you know soon how it went :)

Comment: Yea, let me know. I've never actually took the time to build an actual template tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)?