# Django: Form in base template

Tags: django, forms, templates

Hi Stackoverflow people,

In my Django project I created a form to register users. This forms can be called through a specific url -> view method. Once the user has filled in the form, presses submit, the same view method will be called and if form.is_valid() is true, then ... simply a standard form, nothing special.

Now, I would like to integrate this little form on every page, and therefore I would like to add it to the base template. I have read that I could populate the form variable through a context_processor, but could I define the process after the submission of the form?

I have created the context_processor.py (as below), added the context_processor to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR dir in the settings (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166055/show-a-form-in-my-template-base-using-django)):

```
from app.forms import Form

def registration_form(request):
return {
        registration_form : Form()
        }
```

**First of all, the form variable won't be displayed.
And secondly, how do I manipulate the form submission?**

I think I misunderstanding the context_processor of Django and would be more than happy about comments on the overall process.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how are you trying to access to form in your template? you probably don't want to use a function name as your dictionary key, maybe you want

```
return {
    'registration_form': Form(),
}
```

not sure what you mean by manipulate the form submission, but i guess you'd need all the form processing logic in your context processor

```
if request.POST:
    form = Form(request.POST)
    # validate etc
```

Comment: +1... And he needs to add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The form is now displayed. The '' made the difference. Regarding the validation: how can I return possible errors to the form if it is embedded in the base template? render_to_response('base.html', ...) did not work. What is the best way to approach it?

Comment: it's all handled in the form. try the most basic way of including the form in your template to see the defaults: `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: Where do you validate it? I got it to display but the functionalities is not working

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating context processor, create template tag for the purpose and place the tag in base.html

for form submission and displaying errors use ajax, and front-end validations.