# Trying to include django form in my base.html, but not rendering in other templates?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-haystack

I'm using django haystack to search and want to include the form in my base.html file so that it will show up in all of my templates. It will show up on the when I load to my default url, but I can't get the form tag, {{ form.as_table }}, to show up when I load the results template. The html form is still there, but the form tag isn't.

This is all included in base.html

```
<form method="get" action=".">
    <table>
        ##{{ form.as_table }} ## this doesn't show up when loading the results template
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, only your home view defines `form` in your context. **ALL** of your views must define it:

```
context['form'] = MyFormClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Template Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166055/show-a-form-in-my-template-base-using-django), it worked for me.